# Python TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern - while using Arrays

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to see if a set of employee names in file 'names' are present in another file- 'record'. If yes, I want to capture the employee number from file 'record'. The names are written differently in each file (think first name first in 'names' vs. last name first in 'record') although they are the same person. Therefore, in 'names' I've separated each element in the name into four columns - n1, n2, n3, n4. I need the following to happen:

1. Check if for every employee in 'names', the value in each n1, n2, n4, n3 appear in employee name column in 'record'.
2. If 1 is yes then flag that the name is present.
3. Capture the row number of where it appears in 'record'.
4. Use iloc and row number to extract employee number from 'record' for the name which was found.

In the dataframe 'record', the Employee name is in column 8 and the employee number is in column 2.
In the dataframe 'names' the elements of the employee name are in columns 2, 3, 4, 5

The following is the looping that I am using:

```
for i in range(len(names)):
    x1 = record.index[record.iloc[:, 8].str.contains(names.iloc[i, 3])].values
    if x1.size > 0:
        x2 = record.index[record.iloc[:, 8].str.contains(names.iloc[i, 2])].values
        if x2.size > 0:
            if names.iloc[i, 4] is not None:
                x3 = record.index[record.iloc[:, 8].str.contains(names.iloc[i, 4])].values
                if x3.size > 0:
                    if names.iloc[i, 5] is not None:
                        x4 = record.index[record.iloc[:, 8].str.contains(names.iloc[i, 5])].values
                        if x4.size > 0:
                            flag = 1
                            loc = x4[0]
                        else:
                            flag = 0
                    else: 
                        flag = 1
                        loc = x3[0]
                else:
                    flag = 0
            else:
                flag = 1
                loc = x2[0]
        else:
            flag = 0
    else:
        flag = 0
                
    if flag == 1:
        names.iloc[i, 6] = record.iloc[loc,2]
```

While executing this, I get an error in the second line:

```
----> 2     x1 = record.index[record.iloc[:, 8].str.contains(names.iloc[i, 3])].values
TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern
```

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong

Comment: If you print `names.iloc[i, 3])` what does it say? Is it None by chance?

Comment: Correct. If last names are absent then I see that it is None. However I have removed those cases.